# SSH into a box, immediately background the process, then continue as the original user in a bash script

Tags: bash, ssh, background, fork

I need to script a way to do the following (note all is done on the local machine as root):

```
runuser -l user1 -c 'ssh localhost' &
runuser -l user1 -c 'systemctl --user list-units'
```

The first command should be run as root. The end goal is to log in as "user1" so that if any user ran `who` "user1" will appear in this list. Noticed how the first command is backgrounded before the next command is run.
The next command should be run as root as well, NOT user1.

Problem: These commands run fine when run separately, but when run in a script "user1" never appears to show up when running `who`. Here is my script

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "[+] Becoming user1"
runuser -l user1 -c 'ssh -q localhost 2>/dev/null' &
echo
sleep 1
echo "[+] Running systemctl --user commands as root."
runuser -l user 1 -c 'systemctl --user list-units'
echo "[+] Killing active ssh sessions."
kill $(ps aux | grep ssh | grep "^user1.*" | grep localhost | awk '{print$2}') 2>/dev/null
echo "[+] Done."
```

When running the script it looks like the script is able to ssh into the system but `who` does not show the user logged in, nor do any `ps aux` output show a ssh session. Note: I commented out the `kill` line to confirm if the process stays, which I do not see it at all.
How do I make the bash script fork two processes. Process 1 goal is to login as "user1" and wait. Then process 2 is to perform commands as root while user1 is logged in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My goal is to run systemctl --user commands as root via script. If your familiar with systemctl --user domain, there is no way to manage systemctl --user units, without the user being logged in via traditional methods (ssh, direct terminal, or gui). I cannot "su - user1" as root either. So I want to force an ssh session as root to the vdns11 user via runuser commands. Once the user is authenticated and shows up via who I can run systemctl --user commands. How can I keep the ssh session active in my code?

With this additional info, the question essentially boils down to '*How can I start and background an **interactive** ssh session?*'.

You could use `script` for that. It can be used to trick applications into thinking they are being run interactively:

```
echo "[+] Starting SSH session in background"
runuser -l user1 -c "script -c 'ssh localhost'" &>/dev/null &
pid=$!
...
echo "[+] Killing active SSH session"
kill ${pid}
```

---

**Original answer before OP provided additional details (for future reference):**

---

Let's dissect what is going on here.

I assume you start your script as root:

```
echo "[+] Becoming user1"
runuser -l user1 -c 'ssh -q localhost 2>/dev/null' &
```

So `root` runs `runuser -l user1 -c '...'`, which itself runs `ssh -q localhost 2>/dev/null` as `user1`. All this takes place in the background due to `&`.

`ssh` will print `Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal.` (hidden due to `2>/dev/null`) and immediately exit. That's why you don't see anything when running `who` or when running `ps`.

Your `echo` says *[+] Becoming user1*, which is quite different from what's happening.

```
sleep 1
```

The script sleeps for a second. Nothing wrong with that.

```
echo "[+] Running systemctl --user commands as root."
#runuser -l user 1 -c 'systemctl --user list-units'
#               ^ typo!
runuser -l user1 -c 'systemctl --user list-units'
```

Ignoring the typo, `root` again runs `runuser`, which itself runs `systemctl --user list-units` as `user1` this time.

Your `echo` says *[+] Running systemctl --user commands as root.*, but actually you are running `systemctl --user list-units` as `user1` as explained above.

```
echo "[+] Killing active ssh sessions."
kill $(ps aux | grep ssh | grep "^user1.*" | grep localhost | awk '{print$2}') 2>/dev/null
```

This would kill the `ssh` process that had been started at the beginning of the script, but it already exited, so this does nothing. As a side note, this could be accomplished a lot easier:

```
echo "[+] Becoming user1"
runuser -l user1 -c 'ssh -q localhost 2>/dev/null' &
pid=$!
...
echo "[+] Killing active ssh sessions."
kill $(pgrep -P $pid)
```

---

So this should give you a better understanding about what the script actually does,  but between the goals you described and the conflicting `echo`s within the script it's really hard to figure out where this is supposed to be going.

Comment: Thank you for your patience / walking though my post. 
My goal is to run systemctl --user commands as root via script. If your familiar with systemctl --user domain, there is no way to manage systemctl --user units, without the user being logged in via traditional methods (ssh, direct terminal, or gui). I cannot "su - user1" as root either. So I want to force an ssh session as root to the vdns11 user via runuser commands. Once the user is authenticated and shows up via `who` I can run systemctl --user commands. How can I keep the ssh session active in my code?

Comment: @Dave: that explains a lot, now I get what you're trying to do. I don't know this specific part of systemd well, but if you absolutely must keep an interactive ssh login open, use this command: `runuser -l user1 -c "script -c 'ssh localhost' &>/dev/null" &`. I tested this and it works, however, you may need to use `pstree` or similar to terminate it later. I'll gladly update my answer with more details on this later.

Comment: Thank you @Maxxim that worked. On a side note, I figured out how to accomplish what I wanted with systemctl --uesr without having to script a ssh login. All I needed to do was run `loginctl enable-linger user1`. Now I can use "runuser" commands without having the user1 logged in!

Comment: @Dave: Great, I'm glad that you achieved your goal. I actually expanded the answer at the same time your comment came in. But there's no harm in leaving it that way.